# How to Get args from SP.UI.ModalDialog?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have tried other online suggestions without success.

So...

My function opening a SharePoint dialog passes `agrs` into the prescribed `option` object, like so:

**SETTING UP THE DIALOG:**
Nothing magical here...

```
    function openEmailDialog() {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions(),
            url = '../Pages/EmailDocument.aspx';

        options.title = "Email Documents";
        options.width = 1024;
        options.height = 400;
        options.allowMaximize = false;
        options.url = url;
        options.args = {  DidYouGetThis: true };

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    };
```

Next...

Upon opening the target URL, most online examples recommend the following JavaScript to extract the `args` BACK from the dialog, like so:

**GETTING THE ARGS:**
Remember, this is JavaScript in a new page which was just opened as a dialog...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // This fails because "get_childDialog" doesn't exist
    var args = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
});
```

This fails because the `SP.UI.ModalDialog` object has no `get_childDialog` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `var args = window.frameElement.dialogArgs;`

[The article I used for reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20160412004233/http://www.sharepointdevelopment.me/2011/06/passing-data-to-and-from-sharepoint-modal-dialogs/).

[Live Article](https://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/05/sharepoint-passing-parameter-data-to-a-modal-dialog-and-ie7/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial discussing this very concept. - http://www.sharepointdevelopment.me/2011/06/passing-data-to-and-from-sharepoint-modal-dialogs/